# What regular expression will match a pattern or be empty?

Tags: regex

I need regular expression that matches a pattern or is empty.

Right now I have an expression...

```
"\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4}/x"
```

... which matches US phone numbers. However, it is valid for the string I'm testing to be empty. If the string has any value in it at all, it must match the expression.

I have other patterns which match US postal codes, etc that need the same conditional.

What is the best way to achieve this in the same expression?

**Clarification**: I am using the RegexValidator in the Validation Application Block from Microsoft. An example of using this is as follows:

```
[StringLengthValidator(0, 100, MessageTemplate = "Email must be between {3} and {5}")]
[RegexValidator(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", MessageTemplate = "Valid Email Required.")]
public string EmailAddress
{
    get { return _EmailAddress; } 
    set { SetValue<string>(ref _EmailAddress, value); }
}
```

This is why I need the solution to be in one expression.

Comment: What's the /x at the end of your regex for? In Perl or PHP it would mean free-spacing mode, but .NET doesn't use that syntax.

Comment: Ah.. don't know actually. I just lifted it off a site somewhere.  I'll remove it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wrap the entire regex in parens and place a ? at the end:

```
(\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4}/x)?
```

Comment: worked like a charm.  i knew it would be something simple like this. :)

Comment: actually... this doesn't work right.  the trailing question mark appears to make the regex too forgiving.  For example, 555-1234 will now match but it shouldn't.

Comment: Assuming your original regex works, you can try: 
\B|\\(?\d{3}\\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4}/x
Which should be "empty string" OR your regex

Comment: Same issue. My original regex (without the /x) works on this test site (http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp). If I add the options you suggest then I can type anything in the test and it passes.

Comment: \B means "not a word boundary". It will match an empty string, but it doesn't communicate your intention very well. Your original suggestion is much better, and should have worked.

Comment: Found the issue... yours works fine if I add the ^ at the front and a $ at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Alan. I never actually use \B

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your regex with `(?:<your_regex>)?`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@"^(?:(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\)|[-\s.])\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4})?$"
```

The `(?(1)\)|[-\s.])` part is a conditional construct. It says "If there was a '(' at the beginning (which we know because group #1 matched something), match a ')' here; otherwise match a hyphen, whitespace or dot."  And wrapping the whole thing in `(?:...)?` allows it to match an empty string, just as Kevin said; if that didn't work for you, you must have misplaced one of the parens (or maybe one of the backslashes).

I added the `^` and `$` anchors for testing purposes; in a validator control they shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Curiously, your regex completely crashes the expressing checking site I've been using (http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp).  However, +1 because the general idea works.

Comment: Do you know if that site uses the .NET regex engine? It works fine here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx